# Angular crazy booleans party

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Well, George Boole's skeleton must be feeling some pain at its tomb, since my booleans just became crazy and began mounting parties. I really think they want to rebel to me.

Now being more serious: probably I'm missing something at the $watch methods, or using controllers unproperly, but this is what is happening, check:

My controller:

```
var ctrls = angular.module('controllers', []);

ctrls.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.showChart = false;
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.labels = [];
    $scope.dataTemp = "";
    $scope.labelsTemp = "";

    $scope.$watch("dataTemp", function(){
        checkChart();
        $scope.data = $scope.dataTemp.split(",");


    });
    $scope.$watch("labelsTemp", function(){
        checkChart();
        $scope.labels = $scope.labelsTemp.split(",");

    });

    function checkChart(){
        console.log($scope.dataTemp.length + ", "+$scope.labelsTemp.length +" : ("+($scope.data.length > 0)+", "+($scope.data.length > 0)+") = "+$scope.showChart);
        if($scope.data.length > 0 && $scope.labels.length > 0){
            $scope.showChart = true;
        } else {
            $scope.showChart = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Remember about that console.log, I'll show in a while *how these little guys are partying (hard)*. Now, the HTML template where my router brings me when I write index:

```
<div class="contenedor">
<form class="main-form" role="form">
        <legend>Inserta los datos para el gráfico</legend>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Título</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Título del gráfico" ng-model="title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Grupos</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Escribe grupos separados por comas" ng-model="labelsTemp">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Datos</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Escribe datos separados por comas" ng-model="dataTemp">
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
<div class="main-chart" ng-show="showChart">
    <span class="label title">{{title}}</span>
    <canvas id="grafico" class="chart chart-doughnut"
    chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

This thing actually works... and pretty well and responsively! The problem is, that I want to hide the chart when no data is written in the form. At the beginning, it is succesfully hidden, but once I write something, **both boolean functions at checkChart() evaluate to true, somehow**, so activating the ng-show directive.

Take a look at my console.log output when writing 1 character, then removing it, then writing another, and then writing it:

```
0, 0 : (false, false) = false         << Two initial outputs without user
0, 0 : (true, true) = false           << interaction (I don´t know why this
                                         happens)
0, 1 : (true, true) = true
0, 0 : (true, true) = true 
0, 1 : (true, true) = true 
0, 0 : (true, true) = true
```

What am I missing? This makes absolutely zero sense.

Comment: Don't more alcohol to your booleans so they get crazy. Or wait until they grow old enough so they get tired of partying and staying up late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you split the empty string i.e `datatemp` and `labelsTemp` like this:

```
$scope.data = $scope.dataTemp.split(',')
```

This returns an array with empty string. So `$scope.data` is actually an array with an empty string as one element in it like this:

```
$scope.data == ['']
```

So the length of `$scope.data` and `$scope.labels` is 1 now.

hence the if condition becomes true and `$scope.showChart` becomes true again.

hope it helps

Comment: That helped! Yeah, I was almost sure that this was the problem, I changed the condition to > 1, since it should have two labels to make sense. Thank you!